# Angular correct way to use two component with same logic

Tags: angular

I have one component for two pages (search and categories)
When search request equals to category I do redirect to the categories page. These pages have only a few differents, on the categories page showing two divs at the top and bottom (before and after search results). I think the better way is to split that into two components but I don't want copy template and methods, what the correct way to do that?

Comment: to share logic between components, the recommended way is to use Services (see https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

Comment: show some of implementation